# How to have default and optional arguments?

Tags: elixir

I have this function

```
    def start(data, opts \\ [pages: 17, depth: 3]) do
        maxPages = opts[:pages]
        maxDepth = opts[:depth]
        IO.puts maxPages
        IO.puts maxDepth
    end
```

When I do `Program.start("data", pages: 8)` then I want it to print `8` and `3` but it only prints `8`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could go with [`Keyword#get/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Keyword.html#get/3) instead, like:

```
def start(data, opts \\ []) do
    maxPages = Keyword.get(opts, :pages, 17)
    maxDepth = Keyword.get(opts, :depth, 3)
    IO.puts maxPages
    IO.puts maxDepth
end
```

Or alternatively, [`Keyword#merge/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Keyword.html#merge/2) pass *in* `opts` with some defaults:

```
def start(data, opts \\ []) do
    finalOpts = Keyword.merge([pages: 17, depth: 3], opts)
    maxPages = finalOpts[:pages]
    maxDepth = finalOpts[:depth]
    IO.puts maxPages
    IO.puts maxDepth
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

With map instead of keyword list is in my opinion more compact / nicer:

```
defmodule U2 do
  def format(value, opts \\ %{}) do
    opts = %{unit: "kg", decimals: 2} |> Map.merge(opts)
    "#{Float.to_string(value, [decimals: opts.decimals])} #{opts.unit}"
  end
end
IO.inspect U2.format 3.1415                            # "3.14 kg"
IO.inspect U2.format 3.1415, %{decimals: 3}            # "3.142 kg"
IO.inspect U2.format 3.1415, %{decimals: 3, unit: "m"} # "3.142 m"
IO.inspect U2.format 3.1415, %{unit: "Pa"}             # "3.14 Pa"
```